# HTML5 canvas drawImage clips incorrect size image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have been trying to use HTML5 canvas drawImage to get a still poster out of a video, but the javascript code as follows captures only part of the frame and I don't seem to know why? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<video muted="" id="video" preload="auto" loop="" 
autoplay="auto" src="https://funpd.com/uploads/14094-when-your-crush-stares-at-you.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
<button onclick="capture();">Capture</button> <br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
function capture(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can visit https://funpd.com/test for reference. I want to capture an entire frame of video and the code above captures only a part of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `width` and the `height` of the canvas accordingly beforehand.

i.e.

```
canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
...
```

Comment: @h-b it's working. Now, how do I assign this clipped image as a poster to video?

Comment: You can get the image as a data URL and assign it to an `img.src`. Please check stackoverflow for that, it surely has been asked before, it is not relevant to this question (also please do not try to change the question now, if anything, ask a new one if you do not find a solution to that)

Comment: @priyaverma: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Answer (score 3):

Default `canvas` size is 300x150 pixels (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement).
Either you resize the canvas to fit the video (as suggested in the other answer), or you can use the "long" variant of [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), where you can specify the target rectangle too, and thus resize the video to fit your canvas.

To keep the aspect ratio correct, and perhaps to position the image centered on the canvas, a bit of maths can be applied:

```js
function capture(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var cw=canvas.width;
  var ch=canvas.height;
  var vw=video.videoWidth;
  var vh=video.videoHeight;
  if(cw/ch<vw/vh){
    var th=cw*vh/vw;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, vw, vh, 0, (ch-th)/2, cw, th);
  }else{
    var tw=ch*vw/vh;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, vw, vh, (cw-tw)/2, 0, tw, ch);
  }
}
```

```html
<video muted="" id="video" preload="auto" loop="" 
autoplay="auto" src="https://funpd.com/uploads/14094-when-your-crush-stares-at-you.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
<button onclick="capture();">Capture</button> <br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```